# A queue with lock-free push, but locking pop

Tags: c++, multithreading

I need to exchange data between two threads - one thread sends data and one receives. I want to send data in a lock-free manner, because the sender thread is a game render thread and locking might have impact on FPS or input lag. But on other side receiver needs to be able to go to sleep when there are no data and don't waste CPU power in a busy loop. Also I don't want to chose some specific queue size - I want let buffer grow at runtime when needed (of course buffer growth can cause locking because of memory manager call, but it will be very rare operation). Finally I don't need to preserve order of sent items (but I'm sending
`boost::intrusive_ptr`, so I need support for non-trivial destructors).

I tried to use `boost::lockfree::stack`, but it cannot block on receiving when there are no data (`pop` method just returns `false` immediately in such case).

How can I make thread sleep while waiting for new data (using STL or Boost facilities) without requiring sender thread blocking on sending?

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered condition_variable? The sending thread can just notify it without locking a mutex.

Alternatively cpp20 introduced wait/notify in std atomic, requiring no mutex on either side.